# How to display data linked by foreign key to mapping table.

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys

I have been using php my admin to create a database and the time has come to display my data in my webpage.

I am struggling to display data linked to my mapping table with a foreign key.

The tables I have are:

**Subcategory**

subcategory_id (pk) |
Subcategory name

**Subsubcategory**

subsubcategory_id (pk) |
subsubcategory_name

**Sub_subsub** (mapping table)

id (pk) |
s_id (fk) |
ss_id (fk)

s_id and ss_id are foreign keys to the respective tables.

Here is the code I am playing with without any joy. Im still quite new to php

```
$dbc = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass);
$sdb = mysql_select_db($db_database);

$query = "SELECT s_id as subcategory_id, ss_id as subsubcategory_id FROM sub_subsub";
$result = mysql_query($query, $dbc)
or die (mysql_error($dbc));

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

$subcat = $row["s_id"];
$subsubcat = $row["ss_id"];

echo "<li>$subcat <span>$subsubcat</span></li>";
}
```

Im probably missing something quite obvious but I've been searching and cant find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in your query you give the `s_id` field new name (or alias) `subcategory_id` (the `s_id as subcategory_id` part in the query) but in your code you still try to access it by the name `s_id`. Try

```
$subcat = $row["subcategory_id"];
```

Or drop the alias from query. Similar stuff with `ss_id` field.

Try something like

```
SELECT 
  SC.Subcategory_name ,
  SS.subsubcategory_name
FROM Sub_subsub M
  JOIN Subcategory SC ON(SC.subcategory_id = M.s_id)
  JOIN Subsubcategory SS ON(SS.subsubcategory_id = M.ss_id)
```

to get name pairs instead of ID pairs.

BTW your table design looks somewhat suspicious... usually this kind of category hierarcy is done with only one table, something like

```
TABLE TAB_Category (
  UID        PRIMARY KEY,
  Parent     FK REFERENCES TAB_Category(UID) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  Name       
);
```

where root items do have Parent = NULL.

Comment: cool! that displays the id numbers from the correct fields in my mapping table but how do I then rather than display the numbers, display data from the table its linked to such as subcategory_name?

Comment: I can't use a single table as I have a many to many relationship going on.

Comment: Well, you have to query the name, something like `SELECT Subcategory_name FROM Subcategory WHERE subcategory_id = {$subcat}`. But getting the names one by one in this manner is probably going to be slow...

Comment: @Richard See the updated answer, added query (untested, typed into editor!) to get name pairs instead of ID pairs.

Comment: thanks for your input. I'll have a play around with what you have told me and let you know what I come up with.